# Why do we even need Hamiltonian formalism if Lagrangian formalism is basically the same at the basic level?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism

I have just started studying Classical Mechanics and I just can't wrap my head around why we legendre transform lagrangian to hamiltonian if it just reverses velocity and conjugate momentum.